# JavaScript delete multiple rows from MySQL db with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have been trying to figure out how to delete multiple records from MySQL with checkbox and JavaScript.

At this moment I have got working script, that deletes only one record from my db (latest id).

For each `product` I got checkbox

```
<input class="checkboxProduct" type="checkbox" name="deleteProduct" value="<?php echo $product['id'];?>">
```

I have a button and JS form (working - It gets all needed id, and I can display them, but can't delete.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var e = document.getElementById( "selectAction" );
    $("#btn-action").click(function(){
      if(e.options[ e.selectedIndex ].value == "delete"){
        var checked = $('.checkboxProduct:checked');
        var id = checked.map(function() {
          return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        if (id) {
          checked.closest(".product").remove();
          $.ajax({ 
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?deleteProduct=true?action=select&id=" + id,
            type: "get",
            success: function(result){
              alert("You have successfully deleted these products!");
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Delete function:

```
public function deleteProduct(){
  try{
    $product_id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM products WHERE id=('$product_id')");
    $stmt->execute();
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: `mysite.com/?deleteProduct=true&action=select&id=1%20or%201%3D1%3B%20--%20gonner`

Comment: It should be `&action`, not `?action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `IN` to match against a list, not `=`. And you can't put all the IDs into a single string, they need to be separate items in the literal list.

You should use a parametrized statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$product_id = explode(',', $_GET['id']);
// Create a set of ?, ?, ?, ... placeholders the same length as the product ID array
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($product_id), '?'));
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM products WHERE id IN ($placeholders)");
$stmt->execute($product_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really fine. Will accept answer, when can.